# How to use an or operator in typescript when also using an or operator in a function to determine if undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

My problem lies with the function since I'm using an or operator to determine if value is undefined. Typescript doesn't let me assign a type that doesn't include both of the values.

```js
export const displayLanguageLabel = (
    objects: {
        value: string;
        label: string;
    }[],
    property: NotificationObjectType | FormValues | ContentType,
) => objects.find((lang) => lang.value === (property.fallbackLanguage || property.language));
```

And the errors I'm getting:

> Property 'fallbackLanguage' does not exist on type
> 'NotificationObjectType | ContentType | FormValues'.   Property
> 'fallbackLanguage' does not exist on type 'ContentType'.

> Property 'language' does not exist on type 'NotificationObjectType | ContentType | FormValues'.
> Property 'language' does not exist on type 'NotificationObjectType'.

Comment: I'd recommend reading https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html.

Comment: _"This isn't my code, just code I'm applying TS to"_ - what exactly does that mean? Unless you're happy throwing `any` around there are plenty of things you can do in JS that TS will prevent (which is basically the point of it).

Comment: `"language" in property ? findByValue(objects, property.language) : findByValue(objects, property.fallbackLanguage);`

Comment: Point is I wouldn't of done it this way but looking at it I think it's a perfectly valid way of approaching this problem and I shouldn't have to add more lines to check if(typeof ...) to satisfy TS. Or even property.fallbackLanguage ? property.fallbackLanguage : property.language which TS still doesn't like.